Updating property of Ui State in Compose
I have a ViewModel that stores state for the screen. There are two states: Loading and Menu.
public sealed class UiState {
    public class Loading(
        @StringRes public val message: Int
    ) : UiState()

    public data class Menu(
        @StringRes public val errorMessage: Int? = null
    ) : UiState()

    public companion object {
        public val Initial: UiState = Menu()
    }
}

I want to add a property val isButtonVisible: Boolean to the Menu state, which will add or remove a button on the screen.
I don't know how to do this correctly. Let's say I store the current state in the _uiState variable and set either Loading or Menu there. How can I correctly update the property of Menu? In _uiState.update { } I should check every time that state is equal to Menu and then set its isButtonVisible property? If at some point I switch the state to Loading, then how can I then return the Menu with the isButtonVisible property recorded?
Here the code of switching state:
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState.Initial)
    public val uiState: StateFlow<UiState>
        get() = _uiState.asStateFlow()

viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    _uiState.update { Loading(message = R.string.preparing_game_please_wait) }

    val board = try {
        generateSudokuUseCase.get().invoke()
    } catch (ex: SudokuNotGenerated) {
        _uiState.update {
            UiState.Menu(
                errorMessage = R.string.err_generate_sudoku
            )
        }
        return@launch
    }

    val insertedBoardUid = createBoardUseCase.get().invoke(board)
    navigateToGame(insertedBoardUid)

    _uiState.update {
        UiState.Menu()
    }
}

Full code of ViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
public class HomeViewModel
@Inject
internal constructor(
    private val appNavigator: AppNavigator,
    private val createBoardUseCase: Provider<CreateBoardUseCase>,
    private val generateSudokuUseCase: Provider<GenerateSudokuUseCase>,
    private val getLastGameUseCase: Provider<GetLastGameUseCase>,
    private val getCurrentYearUseCase: Provider<GetCurrentYearUseCase>
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState.Initial)
    public val uiState: StateFlow<UiState>
        get() = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    public val currentYear: String
        get() = getCurrentYearUseCase.get().invoke()

    public fun onStartClick() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _uiState.update { Loading(message = R.string.preparing_game_please_wait) }

            val board = try {
                generateSudokuUseCase.get().invoke()
            } catch (ex: SudokuNotGenerated) {
                _uiState.update {
                    UiState.Menu(
                        errorMessage = R.string.err_generate_sudoku
                    )
                }
                return@launch
            }

            val insertedBoardUid = createBoardUseCase.get().invoke(board)
            navigateToGame(insertedBoardUid)

            _uiState.update {
                UiState.Menu()
            }
        }
    }

    public fun onContinueGameClick() {
        TODO("In Development")
    }

    public fun onSettingsClick() {
        TODO("In Development")
    }

    public fun onRecordsClick() {
        TODO("In Development")
    }

    private fun navigateToGame(boardUid: Long) {
        appNavigator.tryNavigateTo(Destination.GameScreen(boardUid = boardUid))
    }
}


i think you’re trying to put too much into a single state property. It’s not intended for storing a history of previous states that you can go back to. If the Menu holds data that’s still valid even as we’re showing that we are loading something, then that data is still part of the current app state, so it should be in a separate state property than whatever state is tracking whether we are loading or not. Alternatively, you could organize your screens into different fragments and use navigation.

I think that companion object with property inside it could be replaced with the simpler public object Initial: Menu() and this would also not be violating conventions of capitalization.

well, you can create a internal viewModel state (a data class ) and map it to the uiState. For more information https://medium.com/bumble-tech/crash-course-on-the-android-ui-layer-part-1-2094221a9be3

@Tenfour04 I guess you're right. I'll try to move the mutable properties into separate MutableStateFlows and then collect them in UiState using combine {}

@VivekGupta Thanks for the article, I’ll get some ideas from there!
